# Bind Click Event to Kendo-UI Button

Tags: events, kendo-ui

I am using [Kendo-UI](http://www.kendoui.com/) to make a button `delete all`.

I have written this for `toolbar`:

```
toolbar:["create", { name: "delete-all", text: "Delete All" }]
```

It's working fine and adds a button in Kendo grid. But now I want to add click event to this button.

I want to display an alert (like `hi`) when clicking on this button.

How can it be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Grid

```
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                navigatable: true,
                pageable: true,
                height: 430,
                toolbar: ["Edit"],
                columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: 110 },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: 110 },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: 110 },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 90}],
                editable: false
            });
```

My Edit button Event

```
  $('.k-grid-Edit').on("click", function () {

                alert('hi');

            });
```

When you create `button` in `kendo-grid-toolbar` kendo dynamicaly genarate `button class`.
I have edit button in my grid so its class is  `k-grid-Edit`.

Answer (score 0):

After initializing the grid add the following code:

```
$('.k-grid-delete-all').on("click", function () {
    alert('hi');
});
```

Basically, you need to define a handler using as selector a CSS class that is the result of concatenating `.k-grid-` and the `name` of your `button` in the `toolbar`.